# viewport - user-scalable=yes doesn't work

Tags: cordova, viewport

I'm developing Phonegap app based on android sdk and Eclipse.
Just took the default code and added the `<meta>` for scalability, but it doesn't let me to zoom in or out in Android SGS2 device. (Didn't checked on iPhone cause I don't have.)

The code is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" 
        content="user-scalable=yes" />
  <!--<meta name="viewport" 
        content="user-scalable=yes, 
                initial-scale=1, 
                maximum-scale=4, 
                minimum-scale=1, 
                width=device-width, 
                height=device-height, 
                target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
                 -->
    <title>First App</title>
  <script src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
  <script>
     function onLoad(){
          document.addEventListener("deviceready",
                onDeviceReady, true);
     }
     function onDeviceReady(){
                navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is working!!");
     }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad();">
       <h1>Welcome to PhoneGap</h1>
       <h2>Edit assets/www/index.html</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

On Android, did you also enable zoom after loadUrl like this?

```
super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 80000);

WebSettings settings = super.appView.getSettings();
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
```

Personally, unless you really need to support it, enabling zoom is really asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **1** instead of **yes** for **user-scalable**:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=1" />
```

It can be set to either **yes** or **1**

*The **user-scalable** property is translated into 'user-zoom' with the following value translations.*

1. yes and no are translated into 'zoom' and 'fixed' respectively.
2. Numbers ≥ 1, numbers ≤ -1, device-width and device-height are mapped to 'zoom'
3. Numbers in the range <-1, 1>, and unknown values, are mapped to 'fixed'

See Reference:

[W3C CSS Device Adaptation Spec: user-scalable](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/#user-scalable0)

And this:

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/